# Play framework app on heroku can't seem to find default messages file

Tags: heroku, playframework

Our play app on heroku can't seem to find the system default play/resources/messages file. So things like validation errors are showing "validation.required" as the error message rather than the string "Required". The code is working fine locally, and in a war deployment. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: As a workaround for the moment I have copied the messages from the system file into our app local messages file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for pointing it out. Looks like we were a little too aggressive in our slimming down of the framework to conserve slug size. Should be fixed now if you want to try again.

Comment: If this is already happening on an existing app you'll either need to destroy and recreate it or change your play version, deploy, and then change it back. In both cases you'll be triggering a new download of the framework. Read more here: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-version-upgrade